# Objective-C add more UIButton horizontally

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am using a open source `UIAlertView`.View is

[image]

I want to add more button like horizontally, one in left side and another in right of BYE button, like this one

[image]

my using source-code are bellow

```
-(void)popUPView{

    UIView* contentView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor klcLightGreenColor];
    contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0;

    UILabel* dismissLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    dismissLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    dismissLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    dismissLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    dismissLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:32.0];
    dismissLabel.text = @"Hi.";

    UIButton* dismissButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    dismissButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    dismissButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 20, 10, 20);
    dismissButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor klcGreenColor];
    [dismissButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [dismissButton setTitleColor:[[dismissButton titleColorForState:UIControlStateNormal] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    dismissButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0];
    [dismissButton setTitle:@"Bye" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    dismissButton.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0;

    [contentView addSubview:dismissLabel];
    [contentView addSubview:dismissButton];


    NSDictionary* views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(contentView, dismissButton, dismissLabel);

    [contentView addConstraints:
     [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(16)-[dismissLabel]-(10)-[dismissButton]-(24)-|"
                                             options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:views]];


    [contentView addConstraints:
     [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(36)-[dismissLabel]-(36)-|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:views]];




    KLCPopup *popup = [KLCPopup popupWithContentView:contentView
                                            showType:KLCPopupShowTypeShrinkIn
                                         dismissType:KLCPopupDismissTypeShrinkOut
                                            maskType:KLCPopupMaskTypeDimmed
                            dismissOnBackgroundTouch:TRUE
                               dismissOnContentTouch:FALSE];


      [popup show];



}
```

would you kindly help me how to solve this problem . Thanks is advance

Comment: It is clear in the code you are posting how to add a component [ create it then add constraints] but I think your problem is you can't add subviews to contentView as the buttons are outside the contentView's bounds. I will suggest you add the custom UIAlertView in a new view and add the buttons inside the new one

Comment: @iShaalan thanks for your suggestion . but i wan to  do here .i have work in  constraintsWithVisualFormat . but i am failed to do ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you must set proper leading/trailing values ,

leftView.trailing = rightView.leading

for example if you want to align a new view to the right , you would do something like this

```
            UIView *viewToAllign = yourView;

            UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
            imageViewOn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [self.view addSubview:view];
            NSLayoutConstraint *leading = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                     toItem:viewToAllign
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                 multiplier:1
                                                                   constant:SPACING_BETWEEN_VIEWS];
```

or if you want to align something on the left , just switch layout attributes

UIView *viewToAllign = yourView;

```
            UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
            imageViewOn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [self.view addSubview:view];
            NSLayoutConstraint *leading = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                     toItem:viewToAllign
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                 multiplier:1
                                                                   constant:SPACING_BETWEEN_VIEWS];
```

then you have to create other constraints ( height , width , top and bottom )
after this , you can add constraints to your container view